# ¿Cómo crear un trigger que registre los datos de una tabla y esos mismos los elimine en otra?

Tags: sql-server, login, trigger

Tengo esta tabla en SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE CreatingAccount(
idCreatingAccount INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
userFirstName VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
userLastName VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
userName VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
userPassword VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
userEmail VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
userGender VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL 
);
GO
```

Y este trigger asociado a ella:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ToCreateALogin ON CreatingAccount
FOR INSERT
AS
DECLARE @user VARCHAR (20)
DECLARE @pass VARCHAR (20)

SELECT @user = i.userName FROM inserted i;
SELECT @pass = i.userPassword FROM inserted i;

INSERT INTO LoggingIn (loggingUserName, loggingUserPasword)
    VALUES (@user, @pass)

PRINT 'THE USER HAS BEEN ADDED SUCCESSFULLY'
GO
```

Entonces cada vez que yo agrego un nuevo usuario, se crea un registo en la tabla `LoggingIn` (tomado solo el usuario y la contraseña). ¿Cómo podría hacer un trigger que, cuando yo elimine un usuario de la tabla `CreatingAccount`, esos mismos registros (usuario y contraseña) se eliminen de la tabla `LoggingIn`? ¿Podría hacerlo por medio del `ID`? O, ¿comparando los `varchar`? ¿Cómo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo ideal hubiera sido que tu tabla `LoggingIn` también incluya la información de la clave primaria de la tabla `CreatingAccount` (`idCreatingAccount`) para poder definir una clave foránea con ella y referir a esta en el `delete`.

Ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO LoggingIn (idCreatingAccount, loggingUserName, loggingUserPasword)
    VALUES (@idCreatingAccount, @user, @pass)
```

Si puedes hacer esa modificación, eso sería lo ideal.

De lo contrario, no tienes opción que de usar la columna `userName` como referencia. Pero puede llegar a ser un problema si el valor en esta columna puede cambiar.

En este caso, el `delete` trigger pudiera escribirse de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ToDeleteALogin ON CreatingAccount
FOR DELETE
AS

delete li
from LoggingIn li
join deleted d
  on d.loggingUserName = li.userName;

PRINT 'THE USER HAS BEEN DELETED SUCCESSFULLY'
GO
```

Pero, nuevamente, lo mejor sería de esta manera si agregas la columna `idCreatingAccount` a tu tabla `LoggingIn`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ToDeleteALogin ON CreatingAccount
FOR DELETE
AS

delete li
from LoggingIn li
join deleted d
  on d.idCreatingAccount = li.idCreatingAccount;

PRINT 'THE USER(S) HAVE BEEN DELETED SUCCESSFULLY';
GO
```

**Nota adicional**

Toma en cuenta que los triggers en SQL Server se ejecutan por sentencia, no por registro modificado como sucede con otras bases de datos. Por esta razón, hay que tener cuidado con el diseño de los triggers para que puedan manejar más de un registro modificado a la vez.

Por ejemplo, si pruebas una sentencia `DELETE` del estilo:

```
delete from CreatingAccount where idCreatingAcount in (1,2,3);
```

... verás que el trigger que te propuse va a borrar todos los registros correspondientes en la tabla `LoggingIn` correctamente.

Pero tu `INSERT` trigger en su estado actual no es capaz de manejar sentencias `INSERT` que agreguen más de un registro a la vez. Sentencias como:

```
insert into CreatingAccount (userFirstName, userLastName, ..., userGender)
select userFirstName, userLastName, ..., userGender
  from algunaTabla;

insert into CreatingAccount (userFirstName, userLastName, ..., userGender)
values
('Juan', 'Manuel, ..., 'H'),
('Julia', 'Soto', ..., 'M');
```

En estos casos, aunque el `INSERT` agregue varios registros, solo se va a insertar un registro en tu tabla `LoggingIn`.

Para corregir tu `INSERT` trigger, pudieras escribirlo de esta manera:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ToCreateALogin ON CreatingAccount
FOR INSERT
AS

INSERT INTO LoggingIn (loggingUserName, loggingUserPasword)
SELECT userName, userPassword
  FROM inserted;

PRINT 'THE USER(S) HAVE BEEN ADDED SUCCESSFULLY';
GO
```

**Referencia: [Consideraciones acerca de operaciones con varias filas para desencadenadores DML](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190752(v=sql.105).aspx):**

> Cuando escriba el código para un desencadenador DML, tenga en cuenta que la instrucción que hace que se active el disparador puede ser una sola instrucción que afecte a varias filas de datos, en lugar de una sola fila. Este comportamiento es habitual para los desencadenadores `UPDATE` y `DELETE`, ya que estas instrucciones suelen afectar a varias filas. No es tan corriente para los desencadenadores `INSERT`, porque la instrucción `INSERT` básica sólo agrega una fila. Sin embargo, dado que un desencadenador `INSERT` puede ser activado por una instrucción `INSERT INTO (table_name) SELECT`, la inserción de muchas filas puede tener como resultado la invocación de un solo desencadenador.

Comment: Ya lo pude hacer, todo funcionó mejor. Agradezco el tiempo que te tomaste para ayudarme; revisaré detenidamente todo lo que me has sugerido. ¡MUCHAS GRACIAS! PD: no puedo calificar tu respuesta... tu entenderas JAJAJA